# Evolution of normal of material surface moving at a steady velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions

I need some help with the following question:

> A material surface moves with the fluid with a steady velocity $\mathbf{U_{o}}$. Show that the unit normal $\mathbf{n}$ to the surface evolves according to
>   $$\frac{D_{o}\mathbf{n}}{D_{0}t}+\mathbf{n}\cdot\nabla \mathbf{U_{o}}=\mathbf{\zeta}\times\mathbf{n} + \mathbf{n}(\mathbf{n}\cdot(\mathbf{n}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{U_{o}}))$$
>   where $\mathbf{\zeta}=\nabla\times \mathbf{U_{o}}$ is the vorticity of the flow. Give physical interpretation of each term.

I have tried using tensor notation but I can't figure out why $\frac{\partial \mathbf{n}}{\partial t}$ term disappears and how so many $n_{i}$ terms appear on the RHS. I have tried looking for books on material surfaces as well but to no avail.

Comment: $\mathbf{n}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{U_{0}}$ is a second rank tensor. Note that $\mathbf{U_{0}}$ is a vector.

Comment: Just trying to verify, You've got $D_0/D_0t$, which looks a lot like the material derivative ($D/Dt$) which is $\partial /\partial t + \mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla$. Might the $0$ subscript indicate that $\mathbf{U_0}$ is used for that operation?

Comment: yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

To derive the desired equation, we begin with the equation of the time evolution of the material normal vector

$$\frac{D\mathbf{N}}{Dt} = \bigg(\frac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial \xi} \cdot \mathbf{L}\bigg) \times \frac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial \eta} + \frac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial \xi} \times \bigg(\frac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial \eta} \cdot \mathbf{L} \bigg)$$ We can now transform this equation to matrix form using index notation as follows
$$\frac{DN_i}{Dt} = \epsilon_{ijk} \frac{\partial X_l}{\partial \xi}L_{lj}\frac{\partial X_k}{\partial \eta} + \epsilon_{ijk} \frac{\partial X_k}{\partial \xi}L_{lj}\frac{\partial X_l}{\partial \eta} $$ Rearranging and reforming the equation we find
$$\frac{DN_i}{Dt} = L_{lj}\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{plk}\epsilon_{pmn}\frac{\partial X_m}{\partial \xi} \frac{\partial X_n}{\partial \eta} $$ Using a basic identitiy for the repeated alternating symbol $\epsilon_{ijk}$ we find that
$$\frac{DN_i}{Dt} = L_{jj\epsilon_{imn}}\frac{\partial X_m}{\partial \xi} \frac{\partial X_n}{\partial \eta} - L_{lj\epsilon_{jmn}}\frac{\partial X_m}{\partial \xi} \frac{\partial X_n}{\partial \eta}$$ Returning to the vector notation from earlier, we have 
$$\frac{DN}{Dt}= -\bigg| \frac{\partial \mathbf{X}}{\partial \xi} \times \frac{\partial \mathbf{X}}{\partial \eta}\bigg|[(\mathbf{n} \times \nabla) \times \mathbf{u}]$$Replacing the material normal vector with the unit vector normal to the material surface we find that

$$\frac{D\mathbf{n}}{Dt} = - [\mathbf{n} \times (\nabla \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{n})] \times \mathbf{n}$$  Which is the equation for the time evolution of the unit vector normal to the material surface.